# How can I remove a hidden/ghost Google Calendar (Week Numbers)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, android, google-calendar

I'm currently cleaning up and consolidate my Google Calendar so as to simplify my life.

What I noticed is that Google has decommissioned the "Week Numbers" calendar which you normally would need to subscribe to. Instead, they turned this into a feature baked into the Calendar app itself. You can now go into settings to enable this feature.

Here's the problem:

My calendar apps, including outlook and Samsung Calendar, is telling me that I'm still subscribed to the "Week Numbers" Calendar! I want this gone because it shouldn't be there (I've tested this with a new google account, and this calendar is not there).

---

Below is an image of the Outlook client which has the Week Numbers calendar:

[image: Outlook Calendar client]

---

**Below is an image of the Google Calendar Web App which does not have the Week Numbers calendar for me to unsubscribe from:**

[image: Google Calendar Web App]

---

**And below is the Google settings which does not have any option for me to unsubscribe from the Week Numbers calendar:**

[image: Google Calendar Web App Settings]

---

**Here's how I've tried to fix this problem:**

1. Going onto the Google web app, I couldn't see the subscription.
2. So I figured that I would reinstall my calendar clients on my desktop and mobile device. This did not fix the issue, I'm still left with a "Ghost Calendar" in my calendar client
3. Next, I reset my mobile to default settings and cleared content as if it is fresh. After reinitialising the account, I'm dumbfounded to see that the Calendar is still there!
4. Next, I initialised the account on a completely separate mobile device. Still same result. At this point, I figured it is something to do with my Google account. However, I cannot find anyway to access this ghost calendar to unsubscribe from it.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and have any suggestions on what I should do? If not, how can I get in touch with Google so that they can fix this problem for me?

Comment: why don't you just unselect it in outlook and in samsung calendar, so it won't display ? My guess is that google has that calendar 'hidden' in their system, but it is still visible for third-party apps for compatibility reasons. I see that calendar too on my samsung phone, even if I haven't used it for years

Comment: That's what I do, but my OCD is telling me something is wrong with my account. If you're also seeing it, at least it's not just me. Hoping for a real solution to this problem from google. Surely I'm not the only one being bugged by this annoyance :)

Answer (score 3):

You could to directly remove it using the Google API:

1. List all your calendars to retrieve the 'calendarid' of the 'Week Numbers' calendar using the [list API call](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)
   (click on execute on the right side, it will ask to link to your google account and the full list should be displayed just below). The calendar id was 'p#weeknum@group.v.calendar.google.com' in my case, it should be the same in yours;
2. Now delete this calendar using the [Delete API call](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/delete): 
   Enter the id found in step 1 into field 'calendarId' on the right, then clic on execute. I had to execute this step about 2 or 3 times, because the first it was displaying some authorization error
3. Once done, display again the list of your calendars: the 'Week Numbers' should be missing.